# How do I position an image under a paragraph with no text?

Tags: graphics, paragraphs

I am trying to add an image under a paragraph (with the paragraph containing no text, only the image). How do I do this? I have tried `h` already.

Relevant code (what I tried so far):

```
\paragraph{Paragraph 1}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{image.png}
\centering
\end{figure}
```

This positions the image above the paragraph. Using MiKTeX and Texmaker on Windows.

Comment: \paragraph is a run-in heading so doesn't really work if there is no text although you could use `\mbox{}` to make an empty first line. Similarly as you have surrounded he `\includegraphics` by `\begin{figure}` you have marked it as a float that is not part of the main document flow and it can be moved and re-inserted, so it is not in the text marked by that heading. Perhaps you just want `\paragraph{heading} \includegraphics{...}` ? which would address both issues.

Comment: By the way, please post a complete tex file instead of just a code fragment when you have a question. That way, it is easier to run your code and apply the appropriate fixes before answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `figure` environment will float, which it seems you want to avoid.  Thus, use it without the `figure` environment, and use \captionof` to get the caption, if needed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption, lipsum}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Paragraph 1}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{centering}
\bigskip
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{My fig caption}
\bigskip
\end{centering}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If there is no leading text:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption, lipsum}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Paragraph 1}\hfill

\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{My fig caption}
\bigskip
\end{centering}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Removing the figure enviorment did the trick, and the `\hfill` after the `paragraph{}` was not needed

Comment: @BioTex Glad it worked for you.  The `\hfill` was needed in the `book` documentclass, I believe, but maybe not in other classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\leavevmode` to force the paragraph into existence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Paragraph 1}\leavevmode
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{example-image.png}
\centering
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the most minimal tweak to the original code I can think of that does the job, sort of . See the comment by David Carlisle for more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that a picture is inside a `figure` environment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Title}\mbox{}\\*[2ex]
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\mbox{}` is necessary to trigger the typesetting of the title. With `\\*[2ex]` we impose a line break with no possible page break and some vertical space.